# Nginx adding trailing slash when redirecting externally

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use Nginx to 301 redirect from http://something.example.com to http://another.site.com. The problem is that Nginx keeps adding a trailing slash which http://another.site.com doesn't know how to handle (this site is outside of my control).

**Nginx Server Block**

```
server {
    server_name something.example.com;
    return 301 http://another.site.com;
}
```

- Current result of redirect: http://another.site.com/
- Expected result of redirect: http://another.site.com

Is there are way to disable the trailing slash?

Comment: That slash is supposed to be there. It is the path component of the URL, which for HTTP/HTTPS must always begin with a slash. It can't be empty. If a URL doesn't have a path component, the slash will be added. Something that purports to speak HTTP that doesn't accept a path component with a single slash is so utterly broken that it should never have left the developer's workstation. So something else is likely going on. Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: Honest question, why can I get away with typing `https://google.com` into the browser without a 301 redirect to `https://google.com/` but I can't use Nginx to redirect without a forward slash?

Comment: The browser is adding the slash for you before it makes the request. Then it is being disingenuous and _not showing_ the slash.